# Typescript extract exact Discriminated conditional unions type in iterator method

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, type-inference, discriminated-union

```
export type FILTER_META =
  | {
      type: 'string';
      key: string;
      filters: { id: string; label?: string }[];
    }
  | {
      type: 'time';
      key: string;
      filters: { min: string; max: string  }[];
    }
  | {
      type: 'range';
      key: string;
      filters: { min: number; max: number }[];
    };

 type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;
 type Foo = Unpacked<FILTER_META['filters']>;

// how to determine comparer type from meta object
// comparer:Foo doesn't work
// const comparator = <T extends FILTER_META, U extends Unpacked<T['filters']>>(

const comparator = (meta: FILTER_META, item: any, comparer: any) => {
  const DATE_PREFIX = '1/1/2022 ';

  switch (meta.type) {
    case 'string':
      return item?.[meta.key]?.toLowerCase() === comparer.id?.toLowerCase();
    case 'time': {
      const { min, max } = comparer;
      const compTime = new Date(DATE_PREFIX + item?.[meta.key]);
      return (
        new Date(DATE_PREFIX + min) <= compTime &&
        compTime <= new Date(DATE_PREFIX + max)
      );
    }
    case 'range': {
      const { min, max } = comparer;
      const compItem = item?.[meta.key];
      return min <= compItem && compItem <= max;
    }
  }
};


const genericFilter =
  (filterMeta: FILTER_META[]) =>
  (list = []) =>
    list.filter((item) =>
      filterMeta
        .filter((fMeta) => fMeta.filters.length)
        .every((meta) =>
          meta.filters.some((ft: any) => comparator(meta, item, ft))
        )
    );
```

The above is generic filter fn, which is trying to filter an array based on filter type.
Its provided with array of different filter, which uses the comparer fn to filter out.

How to type the 3rd argument `comparer:any` from the 1st argument of type `FILTER_META`

Stackblitz Link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ku6bq7

Comment: "how to get the nested type of filter for comparer from the meta type?" What? Please describe what you are asking about in more detail. Maybe add a line code that has a type error that demonstrates the problem. As it is, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @AlexWayne I know, its hard to explain, but I'm trying to type infer the 3rd parameter comparer: any from first parameter meta. stackblitz demo might help

Answer (score 0):

The value in `switch(theValue)` **must be the same variable** as the one you're nesting into (i.e `theValue.filters.id`).
TypeScript will know that the current `theValue`'s filters are of the "string" type and not the "time" type JUST because of the `switch(theValue.type)`. **Without it,** (i.e your current code) TypeScript can't know that `id` is a key in `comparer` since it doesn't know whether `comparer` is of type "string", "time" or "range". That's why `comparer.id` is not TypeScript-ly valid

For example, if `fo` is explicitly:
(notice: `.filters` is **not** an array)

```
type fo =  {
  type: 'string';
  key: string;
  filters: { id: string; label?: string }; // not an array (is unpacked")
}
| {
  type: 'time';
  key: string;
  filters: { min: string; max: string }; // not an array (is "unpacked")
}
| {
  type: 'range';
  key: string;
  filters: { min: number; max: number }; // not an array (is "unpacked")
};
```

then this works:

```
const comparator = (meta: FILTER_META, item: any, comparer: fo) => {
  const DATE_PREFIX = '1/1/2022 ';

  switch (comparer.type) {
    case 'string':
      return item?.[meta.key]?.toLowerCase() === comparer.filters.id?.toLowerCase();
    case 'time': {
      const { min, max } = comparer.filters;
      const compTime = new Date(DATE_PREFIX + item?.[meta.key]);
      return (
        new Date(DATE_PREFIX + min) <= compTime &&
        compTime <= new Date(DATE_PREFIX + max)
      );
    }
    case 'range': {
      const { min, max } = comparer.filters;
      const compItem = item?.[meta.key];
      return min <= compItem && compItem <= max;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: meta.filters is an array, comparer is item from the array for each iteration

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I changed my answer.

Comment: comparer type is ```Unpacked<FILTER_META['filters']>```, its the individual item  from the array FILTER_META.filters

```meta.filters.some((ft: any) => comparator(meta, item, ft))```, notice each filters record is passed ast ft

Comment: I know that that's what you did. I know. And from the first sentence in my answer- you can't achieve what you want if you keep it like that